# hide file extension in urls

Tags: php, .htaccess

For some reason this is not working for me. I added -Multiviews option because domain is from godaddy, but it's still not working.

htaccess

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: How is it "not working"?

Comment: What do you mean by `I added -Multiviews option because domain is from godaddy`

Comment: @JonLin url still showing for example page.php instead of just page.

Comment: @anubhava http://alexcican.com/post/how-to-remove-php-html-htm-extensions-with-htaccess/  
scroll to bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this code in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(?:index)?(.*?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: great, it works now thank you. If I want to add "/" at the end of url, what/where should I add that?

Comment: Just make it `RewriteRule ^ /%1/ [R=301,L,NE]` or see update to answer.